# What is the feature of a Google result snippet that this man is describing called now?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets

At [3:39s](http://youtu.be/vS1Mw1Adrk0?t=3m39s) this rather old video from the Google Documentation the man describes a feature of enhanced data associated with the Starbuck website displayed in the search result.  He also invites the audience to visit http://www.google.com/experimental to find out more.  However this video is so old by now that the aforementioned website says nothing about it.

I'm primed to think that nowdays what he would be referring to would be Google Maps and [Microformats](http://microformats.org/), but I was wondering if there is maybe a name for what these are called as they appear in the page snippet / single search result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen a name for that particular widget, but it's not one of the listed [rich snippet types](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1088474&parent=21997&ctx=topic). But also note that the rich snippets come from information you provide, generally via microdata, and that's not what's going on here.

The stock information is basically just some embedded information from Google's own Finance site. If you [search for Starbucks](https://www.google.com/search?q=starbucks), you should see a little extra "+ Show stock quote for SBUX" link under the first result. Pop that open and compare with the [SBUX info at Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:SBUX).